# Which pipes are what in this basement rough-in?

Tags: plumbing, basement

I have an unfinished basement that has rough-ins for plumbing.  I would like to finish it some day, and I'm trying to envision what a bathroom would look like.

What purpose are the pipes for?  Toilet?  Tub/Shower?  Sink?  Wetbar?

[image: basement pipes]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The small one in the top left coming out of the floor is likely for a shower or tub. The larger diameter pipe coming out of the floor is almost certainly for a toilet. The smaller pipe to the right of the toilet that continues up is for the lavatory (i.e. sink).

You can tell these things because:

1. The toilet requires a 3" rough-in.
2. Showers and tubs require rough-ins within the floor and the rough-in must contain a P-trap. So you can confirm that pipe in the top left is for a shower or tub by taking off the cap and pouring some water in it. If it "fills up" some before draining, you'll know it has a P-trap and is indeed for a shower or tub.
3. The sanitary tee in the pipe that continues up is placed approximately correctly for a vanity sink.

Comment: Works for me the stubs look a bit tall but better tall than two short.

Comment: I don't think it merits a dedicated question -- but is there a standard way to pop that cap off, to test if there's a trap?  I don't want to cut the PVC yet :)